# Strange exceptions on production website from HTTP_USER_AGENT Java/1.6.0_17

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, web-crawler, bots

Today we have received some strange exceptions on our production website. They all have the following HTTP_USER_AGENT string: `Java/1.6.0_17`.

I looked it up over at [UserAgentString.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/index.php) but the info is quite useless.

Here's one of the exceptions we're getting (they are all more or less the same):

> System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not
>   supported.

The path that is being queried:

> /klacht/Scripts/,data:c,complete:function(a,b,c){c=a.responseText,a.isResolved()&&(a.done(function(a){c=a}),i.html(g

I have a feeling there is a problem with this bot or whatever is being used to access the website. I don't immediately recognize the javascript being added to the path.

For reference I've dropped the entire ELMAH log over at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XE1PRwRr) (and renamed the host to mysite.be).

Does this happen to other people?
Should I be worried?
Could this be a bug on our side?

Comment: It's not really responsive to your question, but I would blacklist the remote IP address.  I don't like anything that look like an injection attempt.

Comment: Related: [A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225027/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: I've been getting [similar errors](http://serverfault.com/questions/308210/the-java-1-4-1-04-user-agent-clashes-404-with-some-jquery-javascript). The javascript is from jQuery, see [their source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js). No clue why yet, but maybe we can find something that our servers/websites have in common?

Comment: My priority is to figure out the source, this user agent is already very suspicious as it is most likely a crawler written by someone who is obviously not part of our wanted clientele. At this stage I'm just going to wait and see how frequent we get such requests, so far it's been quiet.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/308210/the-java-1-4-1-04-user-agent-clashes-404-with-some-jquery-javascript/308383#308383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vineet Reynolds: this problem is not related to the link you gave.
@Share: this problem is not completely related to the link you gave.

Your call is:
/klacht/Scripts/,data:c,complete:function(a,b,c){c=a.responseText,a.isResolved()&&(a.done(function(a){c=a}),i.html(g

When a ':' character appears in a url, asp.net throws this exception. Always.
There is no way to prevent it. You can only catch it in global.asax Application_Error magic handler.

See [MVC3 and colon in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999301/mvc3-and-colon-in-path)